# Executing a python script from scala giving error while running the same script from the command line does NOT

Tags: python, python-2.7, scala, python-3.x, python-magic

This is my python script:

```
!/usr/bin/python
   import sys
   import magic
   m=magic.from_file('<file with absolute path goes here>')
   print(m)
```

On running this from the command line:

```
$ python script.py
Microsoft Word 2007+
```

results in the output of the **TYPE** of the document that file is. Using python-magic.

Now running the same script from scala using below code:

```
import sys.process._
def compWithLibmagic(){
    val result = "python /script.py" !
}
```

throws the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
import magic
ImportError: No module named magic
```

**PS: I have both python 2.7 and python 3.6 installed on my machine and running the script using any of them from the command line runs just fine so I guess both of them are bundled with the MAGIC packages correctly.**

Would highly appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: what happen when you run `python /Users/Bhat/Documents/Spark/script.py` from different folder?

Comment: Runs just fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer my own question in the best possible way.

While trying to execute the `script.py` from the command line using python compiler **python2.7** was being used and when I tried to invoke the same `script.py` from the scala compiler using

```
import sys.process._
def compWithLibmagic(){
    val result = "python /script.py" !
}
```

it was using **python3** which was getting **unnoticed**. It took me a couple of days to actually figure this thing out and finally I removed all the python2.7 and python3 libraries and installed python 2.7 again and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It works from both **python3** command and **Scala** code for me.

This should work.

```
import sys.process._
def compWithLibmagic(){
    val result = "python3 script.py".!!
}
```